# polymer - how to get next corresponding element in a repeating template?

Tags: javascript, polymer

sorry for the sort of specific question. I'm trying to make an accordion using core-collapse and repeating templates and am facing some difficulties. Here is my accordion repeating template:

```
<template repeat="{{item, i in items}}">
    <div class="accordheader" on-click="{{toggle}}">{{item}}</div>
    <template repeat="{{content, i in contents}}">
        <core-collapse class="collapse">
            <p>{{content}}</p>
        </core-collapse>
    </template>
</template>
```

and here is my script:

```
toggle: function () {
    //get whichever 'accordheader' clicked on
    var collapseGetting = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('.accordheader');
    console.log(collapseGetting);

    //find the core-collapse that is directly underneath it
    var collapse = $(collapseGetting).next('core-collapse');
    console.log(collapse);

    //toggle that particular core-collapse
    collapse.toggle();
    console.log('toggled');
}
```

And now my toggle is entirely broken and won't actually toggle anything. I still receive the 'toggled' console log but nothing is happening. I'm not sure if I'm targeting the next core-collapse correctly, or even nesting the repeating templates correctly. Basically I have 2 arrays, `[items]` and `[contents]` which I am retrieving my item for each `.accordheader` and my content for each `core-collapse`.

Any insight? I feel like this is a formatting or template issue..

Answer (score 0):

Having a quick peek at the docs here:
http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/traversing_next.asp
(See the 'Try It Yourself' example')

I believe you're current code is getting the next '.accordheader' element instead of the next 'core-collapse'.

If I've interpreted the link properly then it should look something like this:

```
$('core-collapse').Next( console.log(collapse); );
```

Never used 'Next' before, but there's my 5 cents.